# How do I add a variable to an existing variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
 var username = some_username;
          view.open({ 'post' : '//domain.com/url/person/" + username + "'});
      });
```

username is a variable and I want that variable to be inserted after //domain.com/url/person/".  I am new to JS so struggling with this.  I was able to do it for other statements using the "+" function but can't seem to get it for this one.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `+ "'` at the end. Just use `'//domain.com/url/person/" + username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'//domain.com/url/person/" + username + "'
```

to

```
'//domain.com/url/person/' + username
```

You opened the quotes with `'`, and didn't close them until the `+ "'`.

Answer (score 4):

looks like you have unmatching quote.
should be

```
view.open({ 'post' : '//domain.com/url/person/' + username });
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes on the `username variable`

```
view.open({ 'post' : '//domain.com/url/person/' + username });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrong string closing. You open with a single quote and close with a double quote, that's not allowed. Also, it is wrong how you end with `'"`, you have to remove that. In short, you have to replace it by this

```
'//domain.com/url/person/' + username
```